# Approximating homeomorphisms by diffeomorphisms on manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ and $M'$ be smooth manifolds (compact if necessary)It is known that every continuous map $f:M\rightarrow M'$  can be approximated by smooth maps.
What if $f$ is homeomorphism; when can we approximate it by diffeomorphism? What if $M$ and $M'$ are lie groups?Exmple: every homeomorphism between surfaces can be isotoped to a diffeomorphism

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to look at Chapter 2 of Hirsch's *Differential Topology*. You might think about approximating both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ by smooth functions and then perturb to get a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work if you have two homeomorphic smooth manifolds which are not diffeomorphic, and there is a "well known" example:

Édit:you have the [exotic spheres](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) that work as counterexample

So you should reformulate you question with the additional condition: $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic, however you might have a result that only ensures local diffeomorphism instead of global.

Comment: You also have "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint" by John W. Milnor.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your example.  There certainly are homeomorphic smooth manifolds which are not diffeomorphic, but not with $\dim \leq 3$.

Comment: You didn’t specify the dimension in your question, so maybe you should refine it ?

Comment: What I meant is that if there is no diffeo, you cannot approximate an homeo bu diffeos

Comment: Both Guillemin & Pollack and Milnor deal only with submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$. I can't think of why you're giving those as a reference. G&P have an exercise to use Stone-Weierstrass to approximate a continuous function by a smooth one in order to prove the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem for continuous maps. That's it.

Comment: @JulesBesson:  I'm not sure what you mean - it's not my question.  The point of my comment is that there are examples of the sort you're describing, but none that involve $S^3$ and its quotients.

Comment: I’m sorry for the references mistake, I tried to find some in English but it seems I failed, I only know in French. I assumed they would be some in these book. Quite unprofessional

Comment: @JasonDeVito maybe I am wrong but if I remember well my example works, I can find some other ones ?

Comment: @JulesBesson:  There are related examples in dimension $7$, due to Milnor.  That is, there are two smooth manifolds $S^7$ and $\Sigma^7$ which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.  (To the best of my knowledge, $\Sigma$ isn't given any any kind of quotient of $S^7$, though.)).  It is unknown if there are so-called exotic $S^4$s, but in every other dimension $\leq 6$ it's known that there are none.

Comment: You’re right I checked on my course, I had mistaken two different objects and I believe that C is linked with S^3, not H i

Comment: If by $\mathbb H$ you mean the group of all unit quaternions $\{a + bi + cj + dk \mid a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 0\}$, its action on $\mathbb S^3$ is transitive and therefore $\mathbb S^3 / \mathbb H$ is a point. As an alternative, if by $\mathbb H$ you mean only those unit quaternions such that $a,b,c,d \in \{0,\pm 1\}$ then the action of that finite group on $\mathbb S^3$ is free, and therefore by covering space theory the fundamental group of $\mathbb S^3 / \mathbb H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb H$. In either case, it's not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^3$, which is a simply connected 3-manifold.

Comment: I meant the group but my example is wrong, it may only be a quasi iso (and I need it to not be a diffeo) but I need homeo which I don’t have here I believe